# How to configure JDBC Connection Pool in Tomcat 5.5 for Oracle R12?

Tags: jdbc, connection-pooling, tomcat5.5

My Database is an Oracle R12 instance i.e 11g.
The Tutorial for configuring the JDBC Connection pool shows examples up to Oracle 10g only.
Link [Here](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-5.5-doc/jndi-datasource-examples-howto.html)

**How do I configure a JDBC connection pool for Oracle R12 in a Tomcat 5.5 instance ?**

More info:: My Machine is HP-UX PA-RISC (Unix)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please refer to the whitepaper to configure Universal Connection Pool (UCP) in Tomcat.

http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/application-development/planned-unplanned-rlb-ucp-tomcat-2265175.pdf